# Misleading wikipedia entry on Banach algebras

Tags: banach-algebras

On the [wikipedia page for banach algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_algebra), under examples it states:

> The quaternions form a 4-dimensional real Banach algebra, with the norm being given by the absolute value of quaternions.

and under counterexamples it states

> The algebra of the quaternions $\mathbb {H}$ is not a complex Banach algebra (for any norm on $\mathbb {H}$)

These statements seem contradictory to me.  Is that the case?

Comment: According to [the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1163885/quaternions-as-a-counterexample-to-the-gelfand-mazur-theorem), the quaternions do form a _real_ Banach algebra but not a _complex_ one.

Comment: Putting the two quoted sentences together, "The quaternions form a 4-dimensional real Banach algebra...", "...not a complex Banach algebra".

Comment: If $A$ is a unital complex algebra, then $\mathbb{C}\cdot 1 \subset Z(A)$ (since $(z\cdot 1)\times a = 1 \times (z\cdot a) = z\cdot a = (z\cdot a)\times 1 = a \times (z\cdot 1)$). But $Z(\mathbb{H}) = \mathbb{R}\cdot 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrases

> real Banach algebra

and

> complex Banach algebra

are **very important**. In general, we define a Banach algebra *over a certain field*, and the choice of field matters. You can't ignore the specific field, here: $\mathbb{H}$ is a Banach algebra over $\mathbb{R}$, but not over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing contradictory.  The first sentence says the quaternions are a *real* Banach algebra, and the second sentence says the quaternions are not a *complex* Banach algebra.  So they're a real Banach algebra but not a complex Banach algebra.