# Why do Quaternions and octonions exist?

Tags: terminology, complex-numbers, quaternions

I have known about imaginary numbers for quite some time now. I also understand why we want them to exist (to have a solution for $x^2=-1$). I also remember reading that the complex numbers are closed under addition, multiplication and exponentiation.

> What are the quaternions and octonions (I remember seeing $j$ and $k$) and other hypercomplex systems (as they are called), and why did we create them?

Also, I remember reading that the octonions are the largest of these hypercomplex systems (meaning that any number in a hypercomplex system is also a number in the system of the octonions).

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you seen the sedenions? As to why Hamilton came up with the quaternions, see [this article](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2689449), for instance.

Comment: For an application of quaternions, you may be interested in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation

Comment: You could have a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529/why-are-the-only-division-algebras-over-the-real-numbers-the-real-numbers-the-c?rq=1. Also, sedenions arise when we remove the associativity property. Finally, you can have a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Dickson_construction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The place to look is John Baez's beautifully written article on [The Octonions](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/octonions/).  The introduction is wonderfully entertaining and the relevant section you want to focus on is the Cayley-Dickson construction.