# Complex numbers in 3 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, quaternions

There was a question about this topic a while back, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751106/complex-number-with-3-dimensions). It is known that there is no great way to design 3-dim complex numbers: any representation will have a number of drawbacks, such as impossibility to define an inverse, non-commuting products, or a solution that is trivial and of no value. I was first interested in this topic by looking at [bicomplex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicomplex_number). Though being 4-dim and similar to quaternions, they do commute. But they don't always have an inverse.

The 3-dim complex numbers that I propose here commute, and many have an inverse. I don't know if they are associative and if they accept a matrix representation like complex numbers, quaternions, or bicomplex numbers. I am interested in an answer to these questions.

I define these 3-dim complex numbers as follows. Let $z_1 = a_1 + b_1 i + c_1 j$ and $z_2 = a_2 + b_2 i + c_2 j$. Then the product is defined as

$$z_1 * z_2 = (a_1a_2-b_1b_2+c_1c_2) + (b_1a_2 +a_1b_2) i + (c_1b_2+b_1c_2) j.$$

The first issue is that it is not compatible with the scalar product:

$$(a_1 + b_1 i + c_1 j) * a_2 = a_1 a_2 + b_1 a_2 i \neq (a_1 + b_1 i + c_1 j) \cdot a_2.$$

Note that $i^2=-1, ij = j$ and $j^2=1$. When the inverse exists, it is given by the following formula:

$$(a + bi + cj)^{-1} = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2+c^2} - \frac{bi}{a^2+b^2+c^2}+\frac{cj}{a^2+b^2+c^2}.$$

I used Mathematica to find the inverse, see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=linear%20system%20of%20equations&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation1%22%7D%20-%3E%22ax-by%2Bcz%3D1%22&assumption=%22FSelect%22%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22linear%20system%20of%20equations%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation2%22%7D%20-%3E%22ay%2Bbx%3D0%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22SolveSystemOf3EquationsCalculator%22%2C%20%22equation3%22%7D%20-%3E%22bz%2Bcy%3D0%22).

**Update**

Another interesting set of 3-dim complex numbers can be found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0008120). The multiplication is associate and commutative, but again, not all of these numbers have an inverse. In fact, fewer than in my own set.

Comment: This gives $1 * j = j * 1 = 0,$ which seems rather strange.

Comment: Therefore $1*(j*j) = 1*1 = 1 \ne 0 = 0*j = (1*j)*j,$ so multiplication is not associative.

Comment: The incompatibility with the scalar product (can't replace $*$ by $\cdot$) and non-associativity makes me think that it has no matrix representation. I am also interested in other non-matrix 3-dim complex numbers that would have better properties. Of course, a nice feature of my numbers is that the inverse looks nice when it exists.

Comment: I have tried to gather some information about some aspects you mention in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1917093). For a far broader view see this [PhD Thesis](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1917093).

Comment: Any associative system is representable as matrices.

Answer (score 1):

There is another construction of 3D complex numbers that has associative and commutative multiplication: [3dcomplexnumbers.net](https://3dcomplexnumbers.net). This construction, discovered in parallel by [Shlomo Jacobi](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.01459.pdf) and Reinko Venema (who is behind the website 3dcomplexnumbers), is easier to construct, but hard to find the inverse.

The set constructions, sometimes denominated as $\mathbb R^3$, is $\mathbb J^-_3\circ \mathbb R$, where we have the imaginary unity $j$ where $j^3 = - 1$.

Every 3D number can be represented as $X = (a, b, c) = a + bj + cj^2$.

$$
\begin{align}
X Y &= (a, b, c)(d, e, f)\\
&= a(d, e, f) + bj(d, e, f) + cj^2(d, e, f)\\
&= a(d, e, f) + b(- f, d, e) + c(- e, - f, d)\\
&= (ad, ae, af) + (- bf, bd, be) + (- ce, - cf, cd)\\
&= (ad - bf - ce) + (ae + bd - cf)j + (af + be + cd)j^2
\end{align}
$$

There's also the matrix representation of these numbers (seeing $X$ as a column vector):

$$
M(X) = \left[\begin{matrix}X & jX & j^2 X\end{matrix}\right] = \left[\begin{matrix}
a & - c & - b\\
b & a & - c\\
c & b & a
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Also, $XY$ (or $X^n Y^m \;\;\forall n, m\in\mathbb R$) can be calculated by the matrix multiplication (and if you diagonalize the matrix, you can even calc $\exp$ or $\ln$ of any $X$).

Note: the module is not necessarily conservative over multiplication. But the determinant always is.

There are two important numbers to remark:

1. The number $\alpha$, where $n\alpha = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} (j^n)^2$ (or $3\alpha = j^0 + j^2 + j^4 = 1 + j^2 - j = 1 - j + j^2$).

   1. $\alpha^n = \alpha\;\forall n\in\mathbb N^*$.
   2. $\alpha$ is non-invertible.
   3. $X\alpha = (X\cdot \alpha) \alpha =\;<X, \alpha> \alpha$ (multiplying by $\alpha$ projects the number in the $\alpha$ line).
2. The number $\tau := \ln{j}$ (or $j^2$, if $\det M(j) = - 1$)

   1. $\tau$ in the complex numbers ($\mathbb C$) is $\pi i$.
   2. $\tau$ and $\tau^2$ are non-invertible.
   3. $\tau^3 = - k \tau$, in a similar way to $i^3 = - 1 i$.
   4. In 3D, $\tau = {2\pi\over 3\sqrt 3} (j - j^2)$.

The set of non-invertible numbers are the plane $x - y + z = 0$ and the (orthogonal to this plane) line between $0$ and the number $\alpha$. In 4 dimensions constructed this way, the non-invertibles are just two lines.

There's even the exponencial circle $e^{\tau t}$, with center in $\alpha$ and passing by $1$, $- j$, $j^2$...

And finally, as I gave you mostly general rules, it's possible to develop many other nd complex structures. The first site I mention shows it for 3, 4, 5  and 7 dimensions, and the use of $\mathbb C$ as scalars in 3 dimensions.

Final note: in odd dimensions ($\mathbb J^-_n$ where $n = 2m + 1$), there's no solution to $j^n = - 1$.

Comment: This seems to be isomorphic to the second example in my answer, so the minus signs in the matrices are not necessary.